Register Sms related broadcast receiver without allowing permission can cause ANR?
I'm investigating ANR issue, I encountered the issue in a screen where user otp automatically inputs the value when received via broadcast receiver but I haven't allowed the app sms permission.
Do this scenario can cause anr?
